# Why is my program not taking the first item in the list?

Tags: python

I'm following Crash Course Python Volume 3, and I am doing Chapter 8-12, which is on functions. Here is my code so far:

```
def sandwich_builder(bread,*items):    
    print(f"What type of bread do you want?")
    bread=input("Type of Bread:")
    print(f"Making your sandwich on {bread} bread with the following items:")
    for item in items:
            print(f"-{item}")

sandwich_builder('turkey','bacon','avocado','cheddar','mayonnaise','tomato','lettuce')
```

However, my output looks like this:

```
Making your sandwich on sourdough bread with the following items:
-bacon

-avocado

-cheddar

-mayonnaise

-tomato

-lettuce
```

Is there a reason why my function won't output the first item in the list? Thanks.

Removing the function "bread", which then set the first item in the list equal to that parameter.

I expected the function to print the first item in the list, but it didn't.

Comment: You didn't specify a bread, so `bread == "turkey"` inside the function. Then you overwrite the value of `break` with user input.

Comment: `bread`, not `break`....

Answer (score 3):

The following line of code sets `bread='turkey'` and `items = ['bacon', 'avocado', 'cheddar','mayonnaise','tomato','lettuce']`.

```
sandwich_builder('turkey','bacon','avocado','cheddar','mayonnaise','tomato','lettuce')
```

You then override the value of `bread` by using `bread=input("Type of Bread:")`.

To fix it, remove `bread` as an argument from your function.

Comment: Just by 4 seconds exactly the same answer haha

Comment: Thank you! I got the right output now:
Type of Bread:sourdough
Making your sandwich on sourdough bread with the following items:
-turkey
-bacon
-avocado
-cheddar
-mayonnaise
-tomato
-lettuce

Answer (score 0):

```
def sandwich_builder(*items):    
    print(f"What type of bread do you want?")
    bread=input("Type of Bread:")
    print(f"Making your sandwich on {bread} bread with the following items:")
    for item in items:
            print(f"-{item}")

sandwich_builder('turkey','bacon','avocado','cheddar','mayonnaise','tomato','lettuce')
```

just remove one unnecessary argument from the function. or you have to pass None to bread.

```
def sandwich_builder(bread,*items):    
    print(f"What type of bread do you want?")
    bread=input("Type of Bread:")
    print(f"Making your sandwich on {bread} bread with the following items:")
    for item in items:
            print(f"-{item}")

sandwich_builder(None,'turkey','bacon','avocado','cheddar','mayonnaise','tomato','lettuce')
```